# AWS Amplify GraphQL query - list all elements and filter the owner's ones in different view

Tags: reactjs, authentication, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have created simple grapql schema:

```
type Announcement @model @auth(
  rules: [{ allow: owner }]){
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  selectedTags: String!
  owner: String!
  price: Float
  description: String!
  image: S3Object
  createdAt: String
}
```

AWS Amplify generates for me `listAnnouncements` query that allows me to get all announcements for their owner so on owner's account I will see only those that he has created. On separate view I would like to list all announcements that were created, also by other users.

I thought that the problem was how I was accessing the query, so I checked `<UserContext>` and `<Connect>` methods from AWS Amplify but it looks like it didn't solve the problem.

Is there a way for user to get Read access to all **Announcements** and could modify only the ones that he has created?

Comment: Does your application allow guest users? If not, you can add all users to a group, either manually with the admin queries api https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin#enable-admin-queries, or with a cognito trigger when they signUp / signIn etc. Then you can add this rule: {allow: groups, groups: ["yourGroupName"], operations: [read]} 
If you allow guest users to use your app, I think you have to use the possibility to have multiple authentication types (with api-key / iam role). Have a look at this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/

Comment: It doesn't so I updated the graphQL schema as you mentioned but as I was getting some errors, I have updated the amplify. After that update I have lost the connections to services I was using with amplify - do you know if there is an option to reuse that previous setting or I need to redo the set up?

Comment: Do you use git? if so you might be able to set it back to a previous version and then run amplify push again

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to set up multiple authentication modes for your `api` (`amplify update api`), for instance you can set Cognito as the default auth mode with IAM as a secondary mode. Once that is set up (and `amplify push`ed) you can add the auth rule on your model:

```
type Announcement @model @auth(
  rules: [
    { allow: owner }
    { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] }
  ]
)
```

You also need to go into Cognito in your AWS console and enable unauthenticated access in your identity pool:

[image]

Double check the preferred roles are set up for both Auth and UnAuth roles, and then check ✅ that little box that says "Enable access to unauthenticated identites".

Lastly, you'll need to [tweak your code to tell the Amplify graphQL client to use IAM for those unauthenicated queries](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js#using-amplify-graphql-client), something like:

```
return API.graphql({ queries.MyQuery, variables, 'AWS_IAM' })
```

I've used this on a couple projects so far, hope that helps you get going!